# iOS Objective-C: How do I specify an action in a POST JSON call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post

I am accessing a JSON web service to retrieve a list of prescriptions by sending a patient ID number. The api is set up like this:

```
POST data:
patientID= idnumber
action= prescriptionlist

Returned Data:
{"Prescription Name1", "prescriptionID1"},{"Prescription Name2","PrescriptionID2"}
```

The part I am not sure about is where to specify the action "prescriptionlist". Here is my code so far:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *scriptrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl.php"]];

[scriptrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *patientID = @"4";

NSString *sendData =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=prescriptionlist&patientID=%@", patientID, nil];
NSData *scriptdata = [sendData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[scriptrequest setHTTPBody:scriptdata];
```

I have the "action" listed next to the patientID, I am wondering if that piece of information needs to be sent a different way. It is successfully being sent to the service, but is returning a null value.

Comment: The way you are constructing sendData with an & between action and patientID, it looks like you are building a query string. If you mean to construct a POST body, you may need a line break instead of a &. But if the web service is a JSON web service, does it expect JSON in the POST body? Then your data would need to be formatted as JSON.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Tried the break, got the same result. The data I send would need to be formatted as JSON?

Comment: If the POST data is name/value pairs as you show, then try setting the Content-Type of your script request to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and leave the & in.